# Как использовать функцию многократно

Tags: javascript, функции

Дан блок `div`. Внутри блока - изображение под номером **1**. При клике правой кнопкой мыши, меняется изображение под номером **2**.

```js
const div = document.querySelector(".div-1").oncontextmenu = f1;
let img = document.querySelector('.img');

function f1() {
  img.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/750x/80/64/3d/80643d2bd195efcb740e340441a4dfd6.jpg";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <img class="img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a9/3c/b4/a93cb4e0316ef9c4db83846550ff4deb.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы картинка менялась столько раз, сколько я захочу, а не один раз.

Comment: вам одну на другую и обратно надо менять?

Comment: да, так мне и нужно

Comment: прочитайте про `data`- атрибуты и пишите туда адрес предыдущей картинки

Comment: А по какому действию она должна меняться?

Comment: при клике oncontextmenu

Answer (score 0):

При клике на картинку правой кнопкой мыши сменяется картинка, контекстное меню не показывается при помощи `e.preventDefault()`
Текущая картинка > в атрибуте `src`
Следующая > в атрибуте `data-img-src`

```js
const img = document.querySelector('.img');

function contextMenuOnImage(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const target = e.target;
  if (target.nodeName !== 'IMG') {
    return false;
  }
  const dataImgSrc = target.getAttribute('data-img-src');
  const currentSrc = target.src;
  target.src = dataImgSrc;
  target.setAttribute('data-img-src', currentSrc);
}

img.addEventListener('contextmenu', contextMenuOnImage);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">
  <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/" data-img-src="https://picsum.photos/300/">
</div>
```